# How to disable systemd's "Time has been changed" message spam in /var/log/syslog on Debian jessie?

Tags: debian, systemd, syslog, rsyslog, sysvinit

Due to combined use of Debian jessie, that uses systemd by default, and [sdwdate](https://github.com/Whonix/sdwdate) (that uses [Slow Clock Adjuster](https://github.com/Whonix/sdwdate/blob/master/usr/lib/sdwdate/sclockadj) ( [gh](https://github.com/Whonix/Whonix/issues/169) )), my system clock is frequently changed.

As a result `/var/log/syslog` gets endlessly spammed by.

```
[...]
Aug 22 13:06:15 host systemd[1]: Time has been changed
Aug 22 13:06:16 host systemd[1]: Time has been changed
Aug 22 13:06:16 host systemd[852]: Time has been changed
Aug 22 13:06:17 host systemd[852]: Time has been changed
Aug 22 13:06:17 host systemd[1]: Time has been changed
Aug 22 13:06:18 host systemd[1]: Time has been changed
[...]
```

Running `sudo service rsyslog stop` stops the spam, but this is not a real solution.

This was not an issue on Debian wheezy that used sysvinit.

How can systemd be configured to not send the `Time has been changed` message to `/var/log/syslog`?

Related:

[How to disable systemd's “Time has been changed” message spam in systemd journal while using sdwdate?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166639/how-to-disable-systemds-time-has-been-changed-message-spam-in-systemd-journal)

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166639/how-to-disable-systemds-time-has-been-changed-message-spam-in-systemd-journal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you're using `rsyslog` for your logging I'd add a filter there to omit these messages. I looked for a method to disable these on the `systemd` and did not find anything that looked like a promising lead.

```
:msg, contains, "Time has been changed" ~
```

You can put this into a file under `/etc/rsyslog.d/time_msgs.conf`. Be sure to restart rsyslog afterwards.

```
$ sudo service rsyslog restart
```

#### References

- [Discarding unwanted messages -rsyslog](http://www.rsyslog.com/discarding-unwanted-messages/)