# How to disable systemd's "Time has been changed" message spam in systemd journal while using sdwdate?

Tags: systemd

Due to combined use of Debian stretch, that uses systemd by default, and [sdwdate](https://github.com/Whonix/sdwdate) (that uses [Slow Clock Adjuster](https://github.com/Whonix/sdwdate/blob/master/usr/lib/sdwdate/sclockadj) ( [gh](https://github.com/Whonix/Whonix/issues/169) )), my system clock is frequently changed.

As a result `journalctl -f` gets endlessly spammed by.

```
[...]
Nov 07 13:46:49 host systemd[766]: Time has been changed
Nov 07 13:46:50 host systemd[766]: Time has been changed
Nov 07 13:46:51 host systemd[766]: Time has been changed
[...]
```

This was not an issue on Debian wheezy that used sysvinit.

How can systemd be configured to not send the `Time has been changed` message to the journal?

A related question [How to disable systemd's "Time has been changed" message spam in /var/log/syslog on Debian jessie?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151638/how-to-disable-systemds-time-has-been-changed-message-spam-in-var-log-syslog) has been solved, but that solution won't work here.

Comment: `systemd` cares deeply about timers. This appears to be triggered by updating the hardware clock e.g. `hwclock --systohc`, are you calling that every second?

Comment: @mr.spuratic looking at the linked source, that seems to be exactly what's happening.

Comment: Yes, that is what slow clock adjust (sclockadj) is doing. @mr.spuratic

Comment: systemd feature request:
`option to disable systemd's “Time has been changed” message spam in journal log`
https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/5207

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The message comes from [`src/core/manager.c`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/core/manager.c#L1888) in the systemd sources. It is hardcoded to use INFO system logging level.

By default systemd logs messages that have INFO level, if you can change that by changing `/etc/systemd/system.conf` to:

```
LogLevel=notice
```

but you will lose quite a few of other informational messages as well.

It might be best to patch `src/core/manager.c` to read:

```
 log_struct(LOG_DEBUG,
            MESSAGE_ID(SD_MESSAGE_TIME_CHANGE),
            "MESSAGE=Time has been changed",
            NULL);
```

(`LOG_DEBUG` is defined as the next higher, and highest level in `sys/syslog.h`), or comment out the whole message.

I haven't found a way to only report timer changes that have a minimum size of X seconds. But if that is possible that would undoubtedly make for a more complex and error prone patch.